# Invalid hook call when trying to fetch data using useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to call `useState` inside an async function like:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useState({});

const fetchData = () => useCallback(
    () => {
      if (!isEmpty(searchParams)) {
        setIsLoading(true); // this is a state hook
        fetchData(searchParams)
          .then((ids) => {
            setIds(ids); // Setting the id state here
          }).catch(() => setIsLoading(false));
      }
    },
    [],
  );
```

There are two states I am trying to set inside this `fetchData` function (`setIsLoading` and `setIds`), but whenever this function is executed am getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

What is this Rule of hooks I am breaking here?
Is there any way around to set these states from the function?

PS: I only used the `useCallback` hook here for calling this function with `lodash/debounce`

Edit: The function is called inside `useEffect` like:

```
const debouncedSearch = debounce(fetchSearchData, 1000); // Is this the right way to use debounce? I think this is created every render.

const handleFilter = (filterParams) => {
    setSearchParams(filterParams);
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect', searchParams); // {name: 'asd'}
    debouncedSearch(searchParams); // Tried without passing arguments here as it is available in state.
// But new searchParams are not showing in the `fetchData`. so had to pass from here.
}, [searchParams]);
```

Comment: the problem is with useCallback not useState; because you call it inside a function and this violates the hooks rules

Comment: how are you exactly using fetchData ?

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI Added sample code for how the function is being used.

Comment: Did you check my proposed answer ? I will try to update it to make it work with the debounced values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook rule you are breaking concerns `useCallback` because you are returning it as the result of your fetchData;

`useCallback` should be called on top level; not in a callback, like this:

```
const fetchData = useCallback(
    () => {
      if (!isEmpty(searchParams)) {
        setIsLoading(true); // this is a state hook
        fetchData(searchParams)
          .then((ids) => {
            setIds(ids); // Setting the id state here
          }).catch(() => setIsLoading(false));
      }
    },
    [],
  );
```

The code you wrote is equivalent to

`const fetchData = () => { return React.useCallback(...`

or even

`function fetchData() { return React.useCallback(...`

To read more about why you can't do this, I highly recommend this [blog post](https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/).

**edit:**

To use the debounced `searchParams`, you don't need to debounce the function that does the call, but rather debounce the searched value. (and you don't actually the fetchData function that calls React.useCallback at all, just use it directly in your `useEffect`)

I recommend using this [`useDebounce` hook](https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/) to debounce your search query

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = React.useState('');
const debouncedSearchParams = useDebounce(searchParams, 300);// let's say you debounce using a delay of 300ms

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!isEmpty(debouncedSearchQuery)) {
        setIsLoading(true); // this is a state hook
        fetchData(debouncedSearchParams)
          .then((ids) => {
            setIds(ids); // Setting the id state here
          }).catch(() => setIsLoading(false));
      }
}, [debouncedSearchParams]); // only call this effect again if the debounced value changes
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved the error. But the `debounce` is not working now. Can you check if I am using it the right way?